# Python OrderCloud sdk extended property filter not working

Tags: ordercloud

I am using OrderCloud Python sdk. I want to filter extended property, for this api is doing get request. I provided a url of get request but it is not working.

I tried to filter other properties like ID, Name,Description and it was working fine. But it was not working for extended properties.

Please Help!

https://api.ordercloud.io/v1/products?xp.Color=Red

Comment: Did you remember to create an `XpIndex` for `Color`?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to index your Extended Property
https://developer.ordercloud.io/dashboard/extended-properties